# Get property of complex structure

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a this code:

```js
namespace structures {
  type Children<T> = Record<string, Node<T>>

  class Node<T> {
    #children: Children<T> | undefined

    constructor(
      readonly value: T,
      children?: Children<T>,
    ) {
      this.#children = children
    }

    get children() {
      return this.#children ?? {}
    }
  }

  class Tree<T> {
    #root: Children<T>

    constructor(
      root: Children<T>,
    ) {
      this.#root = root
    }

    get root() {
      return this.#root
    }
  }

  export function node<T>(
    value: T,
    children?: Record<string, Node<T>>,
  ) {
    return new Node(value, children)
  }

  export function tree<T>(children: Children<T>) {
    return new Tree(children)
  }

  export function children<T>(node: Node<T>) {
    return node.children
  }

  export function value<T>(node: Node<T>) {
    return node.value
  }

  export function root<T>(three: Tree<T>) {
    return three.root
  }

  export function createRender(Component: (props: { children: React.ReactNode; value: Category }) => JSX.Element) {
    return function render(object: object) {
      return Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([key, node]) => (
          <Component key={key} value={structures.value(node)}>
            {render(structures.children(node))}
          </Component>
        ))
    }
  }
}
const { tree, node } = structures

class Category {
  #title: string

  constructor(
    title: string,
  ) {
    this.#title = title
  }

  get title() {
    return this.#title
  }
}
```

Playground: https://tsplay.dev/mLA2eW

I like the syntax for describing "categories":

```js
const categories = tree({
  pets: node(new Category('Pets'), {
    dishes: node(new Category('Pets dishes'), {
      subsub1: node(new Category('subsub1')),
    }),
  }),
  cloth: node(new Category('Cloth'), {
    accessories: node(new Category('Accessories')),
  }),
})
```

But in use its not ok:

```js
categories.root.pets.children.dishes.children.subsub1
```

and have some issues:

```js
// its not ok, it should throw an error
categories.root.pets.children.dishes1
```

I want it to look like this:

```
// good
categories.pets.dishes
categories.pets.dishes.subsub1
getCategoryByPath('categories.pets.dishes')


// error on compile time
categories.cloth.dishes
categories.oops
categories.oops.accessories
```

Is it possible to implement this?